# Why we need to call 'c.set.bind(c)' in this script?

Tags: javascript

This is the url to the javascript in the example: https://github.com/madbence/node-drawille/blob/master/examples/clock.js

Here is the full text of the example script

```
var Canvas = require('../');
var line = require('bresenham');

var c = new Canvas(160, 160);

function draw() {
  c.clear();
  var t = new Date();
  var sin = function(i, l) {
    return Math.floor(Math.sin(i*2*Math.PI)*l+80);
  }, cos = function(i, l) {
    return Math.floor(Math.cos(i*2*Math.PI)*l+80);
  };
  line(80, 80, sin(t.getHours()/24, 30), 160-cos(t.getHours()/24, 30), c.set.bind(c));
  line(80, 80, sin(t.getMinutes()/60, 50), 160-cos(t.getMinutes()/60, 50), c.set.bind(c));
  line(80, 80, sin(t.getSeconds()/60+(+t%1000)/60000, 75), 160-cos(t.getSeconds()/60+(+t%1000)/60000, 75), c.set.bind(c));
  process.stdout.write(c.frame());
}

setInterval(draw, 1000/24);
```

I don't quite understand why this `c.set.bind(c)` in the `line` function call

Comment: So that when a `line` function calls that it had a context set to `c`

Comment: Why? Simply because it doesn't work without - you can try it out. Or don't you understand *how* it works?

Comment: To determine why, look at the module `bresenham` to see what the function arguments are and why they are that way.

Comment: @Adam - I'm guessing the last function argument for `bresenham` is just `callback`, and it's just called, hence the reason for binding the thisValue to the canvas instead of the `line()` function. Would be more interesting to see what `c.set()` does with `this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `set` is a function. You are passing `Function` object as a parameter. If `set` function inside uses `this` then the value of `this` depends on the calling object at runtime. To make it reference proper `this` regardless of the calling object, you need to use `bind`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind